# keep TrayDialog open and submit the data

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have a dialog which extends `TrayDialog` to collect some data from user. I want to pass the values collected to another class without closing the dialog. If I override the `okPressed()` method, data will be passed back but window will be closed.

```
public class MyDialog extends TrayDialog {
    public MyDialog(final Shell shell, final MyData mydata) {
        super(shell);
        this.shell = shell;
        this.mydata = mydata;
    }

    @Override
    protected void okPressed() {
        if (!validateData()) {
            return;
        }
        super.okPressed();
    }

    //rest of the code for text box, buttons in the dialog
}

final MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(new Shell(), this.mydata);
if (myDialog.open() == Window.CANCEL) {
    return null;
}
//here get the data that user has entered in the dialog after they press ok
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't call `super.okPressed()` dialog will not be closed. [Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse/jface/3.7.0/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/Dialog.java#Dialog.okPressed%28%29):

```
protected void okPressed() {
    setReturnCode(OK);
    close();
}
```

And in order to pass data back on okPressed action, I would suggest to provide a callback to MyDialog. Something like this:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    void okPressed(MyData data);
}

public class MyDialog extends TrayDialog {
public MyDialog(final Shell shell, final MyData mydata, MyCallback callback) {
    super(shell);
    this.shell = shell;
    this.mydata = mydata;
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected void okPressed() {
    if (!validateData()) {
        return;
    } else {
        callback.onPressed(data);
    }
    //super.okPressed();
}

MyCallback callback = new MyCallback() {

    void okPressed(MyData data) {
        // handle data
    }
}
 final MyDialog myDialog = new MyDialog(new Shell(), this.mydata, callback);
    if (myDialog.open() == Window.CANCEL) {
        return null;
    }
```

In this case you would need to manually close dialog at some point. Also, Dialog will not block the execution thread, if you use [setBlockOnOpen(false);](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.7/org.eclipse/jface/3.7.0/org/eclipse/jface/window/Window.java#Window.setBlockOnOpen%28boolean%29)